# Both wired and wireless connected; how do they interact?

Tags: wireless, ethernet, wired

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10. I  have both wired and wireless connections active. How do they interact?  Does this arrangement give me better speed than having just one? Are there any disadvantages to this arrangement?

Comment: no advantage other than a backup connection.... there is probably some wild science project that you can do to make them "channel" together to have increased bandwidth, but that "increased bandwidth" would end at you edge device(router/modem/etc). So really the answer is 'no' for pretty much all intent purposes.,, Now locally(in your house) you could benefit if you want to use one connection to go OUTSIDE to the internet and the other to talk to other devices INSIDE your home. If you have a lot of busy network apps running on that PC to other devices, that could be helpful segregating traffic

Comment: What @WU-TANG said is true. But [the future may be different](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/03/dell-latitude-precision-pcs-claim-30-lower-latency-with-dual-network-connection/). This story says nothing about such a system working in Linux.

Comment: Typically, your system will choose one connection (usually wired) and use it exclusively, ignoring use of the other unless the primary connection is broken. To use both connections together, look into *bonding* the interfaces. Most wired connections have much greater capacity and lower latency than wireless, so bonding wired+wireless is rarely fruitful. Also, most folks' ISP bandwidth is lower than their in-house LAN bandwidth already, so increasing LAN bandwidth is unproductive.